# Java - Error with an MD5 string check and REGEX

Tags: java, regex, md5

I don't understand why this doesn't work. And where the problem is.

```
public class MD5hash {
public static void main(String []args){
    String md5hash = "69a329523ce1ec88bf63061863d9cb14";
    System.out.println(md5hash);
    System.out.println(md5hash.matches("[a-f0-9] {32}"));
}}
```

In order to actually do use md5hash.matches, I needed to compare char by char. 
Perhaps I don't understand what the Greedy Quantifier {32} does?

And help would be appreciated, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces in regular expressions are significant. The first part of your regex matches a single hex char, and the second part asks it to match 32 spaces. You need to remove the space. You might also want to allow an upper-case variant. So, this should do what you want:

```
System.out.println(md5hash.matches("[a-fA-F0-9]{32}"));
```

Comment: Thanks a load! Worked like a charm. But if I was going to look through pages and pages of lorem ipsum to find any MD5 hash, I would just remove the **^** and **$**?

Thanks, a lot. :)

Comment: @AdamGreenhill Yes, as then it'll match within any surroundings.

Comment: @AdamGreenhill I've edited my answer. I double-checked and it turns out that `String.matches` already checks the *entire* string, so ^ and $ don't actually make a difference here (although they do no harm). You can use [Matcher.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) to check for a match anywhere within a string.